# Methods to set a session token by url

Tags: java, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, perl, coldfusion

I'm writing up a security document and it would be great if programmers in other languages than PHP could chime in on (perhaps the default) way sessions are passed by URL in their language's default session handler.

```
eg. PHPSESSION=token in PHP
```

Oh, and if yes does it also use cookies?

Comment: I've found this: For Java, it looks like this:
https://someapp.com/login.jsp;jsessionid=[sessid]
For CF, it looks like this:
https://someapp.com/login.cfm?cfid=[cfid]&cftoken=[cftoken]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColdFusion has CFID and CFTOKEN by default in cookie but possible in URL.

Comment: Unless you're using Java sessions. Then you use JSESSIONID.

Comment: If I read well the question of Steven, by default ColdFusion use CFID and CFTOKEN into cookie to track sessions. Period.

Answer (score 1):

[Aurelien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350700/methods-to-set-a-session-token-by-url/5350895#5350895) isn't wrong, but you're probably better off using the built-in URLtoken session variable:

```
someapp.login.cfm?urltoken=#session.urltoken#
```

Or, perhaps better, the generic SessionID

```
someapp.login.cfm?SessionID=#session.SessionID#
```

See: [Adobe ColdFusion 9 References - Standard Session Variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7ff3)